# Implement hide/show for user profile page on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, settings

I am looking to implement a setting to allow users to hide their email address on their profile page if they wish. I immediately thought I could add a boolean value and if the checkbox == true, then it would hide the email.

Would this be a good way to do it or is there another suggestion? Thank you =)

Comment: For a feature as simple as that, a `boolean` value persisted in the db would be your best bet.

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)

Comment: FYI, in case you don't know how to add a column to your table, execute this command:
`rails generate migration AddColumnNameToTableName`.
This will generate a migration file. Inside it, add the following line:
`add_column :users, :your_boolean_field, : boolean `

Then run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: I do but I appreciate it very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
rake g migration add_show_email_to_profile
//in that migration ad a field called "show_email" as a boolean (default true or false is up to you)
```

in your userprofile form you do something like this

```
=form_for @profile do |f|
  ...
  =f.checkbox :show_email
```

and then in your view you can go something like that

```
-if @user.profile.show_email
  %tr
    %td E-Mail
    %td=@user.email
```